# How to force EF Code First to ignore inheritance?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've got a base class `MyBase` which is a part of my data model. I also have classes `MyChild1`, `MyChild2` derived from it in related assemblies.

I want the children to be stored in database and loaded just like `MyBase`. Also I don't want my entity configuration to know anything about children classes.

Is there any way to force EF to ignore that inheritance and user only base class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't it already what happens if you only expose a `DbSet<MyBase>` in your DbContext? Haven't tried, but it sounds like the logical behavior

Comment: Use an interface instead. So your table entities will implement IEntity or somesort.

Comment: Or you can add a [NotMapped] attribute to the properties on your baseclass...

Comment: MyBase is used as an item in other classes' collections. So, EF tries to save it as it's exact type.

Comment: Some of that classes haven't any other properties. But EF throws an exception as it has no information about their mapping

Comment: @Waldemar With a relationship, it sounds way more complicated indeed. I don't know if it's possible to map different entities to the same table, but it's worth a try. Otherwise, maybe you should use different objects in your data access layer and map your business objects in and out of this layer.

Comment: @KooKiz it makes sens. Probably the best solution yet.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your case:

```
public abstract class BaseModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class Child1 : BaseModel
{
     public string Name1 { get; set; }
}


public partial class Child2 : BaseModel 
{
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
}
```

I guess your data should be similar like this (I am not sure your detail requirements, here is just an example):

```
public partial class Example<T> where T: BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public T Data { get; set; } // so here could be any Child of BaseModel
}

public partial class Example: Example<BaseModel> 
{
}
```

1. Use [ModelBuilder.Ignore<>() Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder.ignore?view=efcore-2.1) to let EFCore ignore your children and base.
2. User [PropertyBuilder.HasConversion Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.propertybuilder-1.hasconversion?view=efcore-2.1) to convert your data to/from database.

Here is sample code:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Example> Examples { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        //Let EFCore ignore all models that you don't want it to be a table
        builder.Ignore<BaseModel>();
        builder.Ignore<Child1>();
        builder.Ignore<Child2>();

        builder.Entity<Example>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(p => p.Data).HasConversion(
                    x => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x) //convert TO a json string
                    , x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseModel>(x)//convert FROM a json string
                );
        });
    }
}
```